# Continuous correspondence and function

Tags: functions

How can I prove that given a function $f: X \to Y$ and a correspondence $F: X \rightrightarrows Y$ given by $F(x) = \{f(x)\}$, then f is continuous if and only if F is?

I am also confused by the notation, what do the curly braces here mean $F(x) = \{f(x)\}$? If $f$ is a function isn't $F$ a function too and then the proof is trivial?

Comment: The curly brackets indicate a set: $F$ carries $x$ to the singleton set whose only element is $f(x)$. $F$ is a correspondence, not a function into $Y$. You will have to actually study your course materials to find out what it means for a correspondence to be "continuous".

Comment: I understand continuity of correspondence means UHC + LHC.

Thanks for confirming it is a singleton, my point is that if it is a singleton..then it is the trivial case where f and F output is identical, so F is both a correspondence and a function.

I think I solved the proof because then it is easy enough to notice that continuity of f imposes requirements on open sets that mirror UHC and LHC and viceversa.

Comment: $f$ and $F$ output is **not** identical. $a \ne \{a\}$. They are *never* the same. The codomain of $f$ is $Y$. All correspondences (in this sense) are set-theoretic functions. but the codomain of $F$ is $\mathscr P(Y)$, not $Y$.  $Y \in \mathscr P(Y)$, but $Y \not\subset \mathscr P(Y)$ You need to shed yourself of that concept. $f$ and $F$ are related, but distinct things. The point of the exercise is that the appropriate definitions of continuity for each respect that relationship. Indeed, part of the reason continuity of correspondences is defined as it is, is to make this true.

Comment: Thanks, this has been enlightening